# Handler for method call

Tags: php, templates

I'm in view file and I want to execute a helper:

```
echo $this->url();
```

I want to write the handler for checking if method url() exists in view class.
How can I do it? __get() method is only for object members? Is there something like this for methods?

```
class View 
{
    public function partial()
    {
        require 'view.phtml';
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make use of [**`method_exists()`**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.method-exists.php) in PHP .. Do something like this...

```
class View 
{
    public function partial()
    {
        require 'view.phtml';
    }

}

$cview = new View;
var_dump(method_exists($cview,'url')); // "prints" false
var_dump(method_exists($cview,'partial')); // "prints" true
```

Comment: It's not a flexible. I would like to have something automatically like a __get(); In view file there couldn't be if-statement for checking if method exists. It should take place in a class but I don't know how can I do it.

Comment: Can you show some implementations on where you are stuck ? Update that in the question.